# Parse CSV file by header titles

Tags: python, csv

I have a couple of CSV files with information about different users. Every file has 3 or 4 columns with the first rows being the titles and the respective information underneath it. Such as:

```
Username  FirstName  LastName  Occupation
JSmith12  John       Smith     Staff
```

Some of the columns are out of order or missing in half of the CSV files so I can't simply do *row.split(',')[0]* to get all the Usernames in all CSV files.

My question here is: How would I be able to get and read all the column information by the header titles and not by rows.

Answer (score 2):

Look into using the [`DictReader` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader):

```
$ cat test.csv
Username,FirstName,LastName,Occupation
JSmith12,John,Smith,Staff
$ python
>>> import csv
>>> 
>>> with open("test.csv") as f:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(f)
...     for row in reader:
...         print(row)
... 
{'Username': 'JSmith12', 'LastName': 'Smith', 'FirstName': 'John', 'Occupation': 'Staff'}
```

Every `row` would be a dictionary where keys were extracted from the csv file headers.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I just read one column at a time? I tried print row['Username'] and it gives me all the usernames but then also gives me a Traceback error. Also when I try Occupation, it doesnt print anything but another error

Answer (score 0):

The `csv` [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) in the Python Standard Library contains a class called `DictReader` that does what you want.